# Can not Login to SQL database using Azure portal SQL Database Query Editor preview

Tags: azure

When I login to Azure Portal and I go to the SQL database I created and I click on the Query editor (preview). I am attempting to connect using SQL server authentication. I enter my username and password, and then I get an error message below the password that has red x and The X-CSRF-Signature header could not be validated.

I am using Google Chrome web browser when connecting to Azure Portal.

How do I solve this problem with  X-CSRF-Signature header could not be validated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your computer's clock is set to the right time and timezone or try matching your computer's timezone with the Azure.

Comment: my computer's clock has correct time and timezone. How do you verify the Azure timezone.

Comment: You should be able to find the timezone by googling timezone for the location of your instance zone. For example - East US

Answer (score 0):

This header is created and validated to prevent a certain type of attack against Azure SQL Servers.  Specifically, some web browsers can save your passwords which might then allow an attacker who doesn’t know the password to issue queries using the remembered password.  In order to prevent this type of attack, known as Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF), Azure attach this little bit of extra data, called the “CSRF Signature”.  This signature proves that the credentials were known at the time of the request, not just remembered by the browser.

This security mechanism requires that your clocks are synchronized to within 5 minutes of our servers, to prevent replay attacks with old CSRF signatures.

Please ensure that your clock is set to the correct time, as this is the most likely cause for the error message you observed.